# 2D array returning null with specific value

Tags: php, json

I'm currently trying to fill a 2D Array with data using json_decode. However, it appears to load right, but when I try to get a specific value it returns null even if it's not.

My 2dtestarray.php:

```
<?php
class testarray {

public static $listConfigs;

public function __construct() {
    $this->listConfigs = json_decode(file_get_contents('configuration.json'), true);
}

public static function getValue($list, $property) {
    return self::$listConfigs[$list][$property];
}

public function save() {
    file_put_contents('configuration.json',json_encode($listConfigs));
}
}
?>
```

My testload.php:

```
<?php
    require_once("2darraytest.php");
    $ta = new testarray();

    var_dump($ta->getValue('main', 'canView'));

    var_dump($ta->listConfigs);

    $test = json_decode(file_get_contents('configuration.json'), true);

    var_dump($test);

    $mainList = $test['main']['canView'];
    echo $mainList;
?>
```

My configuration.json:

```
{"main":{"canView":"true"},"secondary":{"canView":"false"}}
```

The output from testload.php:

```
NULL 
array(2) { ["main"]=> array(1) { ["canView"]=> string(4) "true" } ["secondary"]=> array(1) { ["canView"]=> string(5) "false" } } 
array(2) { ["main"]=> array(1) { ["canView"]=> string(4) "true" } ["secondary"]=> array(1) { ["canView"]=> string(5) "false" } } 
true
```

Finally, my question, which is why is "var_dump($ta->getValue('main', 'canView'));" returning null and not true like "$mainList = $test['main']['canView']; echo $mainList;" does?

Comment: you are accessing a static property in getValue but accessing an instance property in `$ta->listConfigs`. The constructor sets the value into the instance property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are accessing a static property in `getValue`:

```
self::$listConfigs[$list][$property]
```

but accessing an instance property in `$ta->listConfigs`. The constructor sets the value into the instance property.

```
$this->listConfigs = json_decode(file_get_contents('configuration.json'), true);
```

So this causes the instance to have access to both a static `self::$listConfigs` and a instance property `$this->listConfigs`.

Try to change the constructor to use the static property.

```
public function __construct() {
    self::$listConfigs = json_decode(file_get_contents('configuration.json'), true);
}
```

Comment: Thanks! This worked, but it returned "string(4) "true"." Is there a way to remove the "string(4)" part or maybe you can point me in the direction I need to go to remove it?

Comment: If you want it to be boolean (true or false) you should remove the quotes (") surrounding it.